# Need to convert symbol to dec in c++

Tags: c++

Using type casting to convert string into integer

```
string str="123456";
int buffer[str.length()];
for (int i=0; i<str.length();i++)
{
    buffer[i]=(int)str[i];
    cout << buffer[i];
}
```

Getting following result    **495051525354**
 which is DEC form of Symbol **123456**

But i want "123456" as a result. Please help!!

Comment: [`std::stoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)?

Comment: Subtract `'0'` (48 in ASCII)?

Comment: You are converting each individual character of the string to type `int` and outputting that value. `49`, `50`, `51`, etc. are all values of those characters.

Answer (score -1):

Got workaround by my self

```
string str="123456";
int buffer[str.length()];
for (int i=0; i<str.length();i++)
{
buffer[i]=(int)str[i] - 48;
cout << buffer[i];
}
```